# Android - using Prebuilt shared libraries that target Armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using some pre-build android libraries, by sticking them in my jni folder and putting this in the Android.mk

```
# Add prebuilt libgdx
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libgdx
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libgdx.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

this copies the file to libs/armeabi

but this library also contains some similarly named pre-built .so files that are indended for libs/armeabi-v7a

So how would I write my .mk file to properly direct these files to their respective folders?

Comment: I har a similar question, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563928/linking-thirdparty-libs-libs-a-with-ndk

Answer (score 3):

Write this in Android.mk

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)       
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE    := TestNDK
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := TestNDK.c.arm.neon
    LOCAL_ARM_NEON  := true
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
endif # TARGET_ARCH_ABI == armeabi-v7a
```

And then specify within your Application.mk file:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```